# stream_set_timeout() does not work in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a chance that the stream_set_timeout() does not work? My function (code below) takes as long as the server needs to reply. If the server takes 30 seconds to reply, the function will patiently wait. I want it to timeout after a few seconds, the function should return null and the website shouldn't be loading for 30+ seconds and instead tell that there is a connection issue.
I'm using PHP 5.4.

```
function request($json){
    $reply = null;
    $fp = @fsockopen("localhost", 1234, $errno, $errstr, 2);
    if(!$fp){
        return null;
    }
    fputs($fp, $json."\r");
    stream_set_timeout($fp, 2);
//  stream_set_blocking($fp, true); <-- I've read in a related SO question that this might help. It doesn't.
    for($i=0; !feof($fp); $i++){
        $reply = fgets($fp);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return $reply;
}
```

Comment: Try putting `stream_set_timeout` before the `fputs`.

Comment: I did already try that. Doesnt help. The sending is not the issue, the receiving is, since the server has to prepare the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're not checking the return value of `fgets()` nor do you check the socket meta data. The socket is not flagged as EOF when a timeout occurs.

The following code should work better for you:

```
$i = 0;
while (!feof($fp)) {
    if (($reply = fgets($fp)) === false) {
        $info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
        if ($info['timed_out']) {
             // timed out
        } else {
             // some other error
        }
    }
    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: This together with setting `stream_set_blocking()` to `true` does it! Thank you :)