# PHP Timeout Read PUT-data from php://input

Tags: php, rest, timeout, put

I created a Restful-API. 
I can read PUT-data from php://input, but I'm not able to set a timeout for this operation. The following script should exit, if it needs more than 1 second for reading the PUT-data. I also tried different variations with methods like "file_gets_content", "stream_get_contents" or set different values for "max_input_time", but the script won't stop if it needs longer than I did set.

```
$handle = fopen("php://input", "r");
$timeout = 1;

stream_set_timeout($handle, $timeout);
stream_set_blocking($handle, true);

$info = stream_get_meta_data($handle);

$putData = "";

while (!feof($handle)) {
    if (($putData .= fgets($handle, 4096)) === false) {
        $info = stream_get_meta_data($handle);
    }
}

fclose($handle);

if ($info['timed_out']) {
    throw new \Exception("timeout");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stream\_set\_timeout() doesnt work in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349123/stream-set-timeout-doesnt-work-in-php)

Comment: No, I read this post, too. My latest code is hardly different than the one in this posts answer.